# How to asynchronizely save image with Playwright in Python?

Tags: web-scraping, web-crawler, python-asyncio, playwright, playwright-python

I'm implementing a python web scraper using Playwright and I'm interested in saving images given their urls (i.e. each url contains and only contains the corresponding image). However, I have trouble finding the correct **asynchronized Python method in Playwright that saves an image given its url**.

By querying "save" on https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-event-crash , I only found `page.screenshot()`, which takes the screenshot of the whole webpage, instead of saving only the image; also, I found some synchronized Python method and methods in Javascript, but they didn't help me in finding out the asynchronized image-saving method in Python. Well, I got really stuck, and I would appreciate very much if anyone could bring me to the method.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not advanced in Playwright, but in this case, it seems there is no need to use built-in methods of Playwright. There is a way for fetch and save images with asynchronous based modules (in Python). You can easily save images with `aiohttp` and `aiofiles` modules.

```py
import aiofiles
import aiohttp
import asyncio


async def save_image_async(image_url):
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
         async with session.get(image_url) as resp:
            if resp.status == 200:
                f = await aiofiles.open('./image.png', mode='wb')
                await f.write(await resp.read())
                await f.close()


image_url = 'https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/15/The_Elder_Scrolls_V_Skyrim_cover.png'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(save_image_async(image_url))
```

Answer (score 0):

1. before page.goto(), you could add a [handler](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-event-response), like:

```
page.on("response", response_handler)
```

2. in response_handler, filter img from url, then save it.

```
def response_handler(*args, **kw):
    try:
        response = args[0]
        url = response.url
        if re.findall(r'\.png|jpg', url, re.IGNORECASE):
            LOGGER.debug("response_handler:%s", url)
            # img_name = f"/tmp/{url.rpartition('/')[-1]}.png"
            # with open(img_name, 'wb') as f:
            #     f.write(response.body())
    except Exception:
        pass
```

Comment: This is not asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution based off @zongtongyi's answer but with a more elaborate example(wasn't sure how best to edit theirs).

So essentially, what you want to do is add a [response handler](https://playwright.dev/python/docs/api/class-page#page-event-response) to the playwright page instance which can do what ever it likes with the received response (in your case, save the image).

Here's an example of an Async code using Playwright:

```py
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright, Browser, Response

async def saving_image():
    async with async_playwright() as playwright:
        # launches browser. Adjust arguments as you like
        browser = await playwright.chromium.launch(headless=True)
        page = await browser.new_page()

        # your response handler
        async def on_response(resp: Response):
            img_bytes = await resp.body()
            file_name = 'path/to/save/image.jpg'
            # save image to file
            with open(file_name, 'wb+') as img_file:
                img_file.write(img_bytes)
                # you can close the page if this is the only image you want to save
                await page.close()
                # close browser
                await browser.close()

        # add response event handler to Page instance
        page.on('response', on_response)
        # visit actual url with playwright
        await page.goto('https://url-to-actually-download-image-from.com/image.jpg')
```

Comment: The operation of writing files is still synchronous and blocking. You may want to use `aiofiles`

Comment: If you combine your answer with an example from @pourya90091 that would be a correct answer

Comment: @DaniilRyzhkov reading the original question, my understanding is that the async they want is more tied to playwright than to actual file saving. The user wants to know how to asynchronously read image bytes from playwright responses. However the file is written is not related to Playwright, and I believe they shouldn't have to tie the question to Playwright if that were the case.

Comment: The question clearly asks for a way to asynchronously save an image

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways you can solve this is by monitoring getting the request sent by an interaction, then getting it's response by `request.response()`.

You can then get the response's body, which in the case of an image URL, should be the image bytecode.

```
import aiofiles as aiof
from playwright.async_api import async_playwright

async def get_dates() -> None:
    
    url = ""
    expected_url = "" #can use * when the url won't entirely be known
    #eg. expected_url = "https://www.example.com/images/*"

    async with async_playwright() as pw:
        browser = await pw.chromium.launch()
        page = await browser.new_page()
        await page.goto(url)
        await page.wait_for_url(url, timeout=5000)

        async with page.expect_request(expected_url) as requ:
            #interaction with element below which sends request (like opening a new page)
            await page.locator("button").click()
            #or if you know the url -> await page.goto(expected_url)
                    
        requ_value = await requ.value
        resp = await requ_value.response()
        resp_body = await resp.body()
    
        async with aiof.open("image.png", "wb") as out:
            await out.write(resp_body)
```