# How to get the blob response of the web page, what are the methods?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, playwright

A website page  https://www.colamanga.com/manga-fh164016/1/98.html
I want to crawl the above image,but it is blob.
[blob images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lK5Rm.png)

How to get blob response,i need plain text then i can convert it to images.Or is there any other way to get the images on the page? There is no restriction on the programming language, preferably Python or Go. Where should I start?

Only when the page slides down will the network request to display the image. I tried selenium and playwright but got nothing.
Example

```
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright
import base64

page_url = "https://www.colamanga.com/manga-fh164016/1/98.html"
user_agent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/120.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    context = browser.new_context(user_agent=user_agent)
    page = context.new_page()
    page.set_extra_http_headers({"Referer": page_url})
    page.goto(page_url)

    blob_data = page.evaluate("""
        async () => {
            const response = await fetch('https://www.colamanga.com/585d5975-7318-4ec0-8739-07747c1b8084');
            const blobData = await response.blob();

            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                const reader = new FileReader();
                reader.onloadend = () => resolve(reader.result.split(',')[1]);
                reader.onerror = reject;
                reader.readAsDataURL(blobData);
            });
        }
    """)

    with open("output_image.jpg", "wb") as f:
        f.write(base64.b64decode(blob_data))
    browser.close()

print("Image saved successfully.")
```

Comment: blob!=base64.  It's binary.  You should be able to just create a file straight from the URL.  I think in Python that's requests.get(url).

Comment: [How to asynchronizely save image with Playwright in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74913951/how-to-asynchronizely-save-image-with-playwright-in-python) may be useful.